# Programatically adding a TextDecoration to a TextBlock causes InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, invalidoperationexception

I'm trying to add a TextDecoration (e.g. Strikethrough) to a TextBlock via a data bound property.

Minimal example:

```
public partial class TextDecoTest : Window
    {
        public TextDecoTest()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            TextDeco.Add(TextDecorations.Strikethrough); //Exception here
        }    


        public TextDecorationCollection TextDeco
        {
            get { return (TextDecorationCollection)GetValue(TextDecoProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextDecoProperty, value); }
        }    

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextDecoProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextDeco", typeof(TextDecorationCollection), typeof(TextDecoTest), new PropertyMetadata(new TextDecorationCollection()));


    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" TextDecorations="{Binding TextDeco}" />
</Window>
```

However, adding of a TextDecoration fails with:

> Specified value of type 'System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection' must
>   have IsFrozen set to false to modify.

Okay, but since you can't really unfreeze controls in WPF, I'm a bit stumped. It works if I create a new TextDecorationCollection, add the decoration and then replace the entire collection, but this isn't really feasible in our case and also feels wrong.
I found several other mentions of this issue, but they seem to refer to a bug that has been fixed with .NET 4.5 (we're using 4.6.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four static properties in the [`TextDecorations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdecorations(v=vs.110).aspx) class are already of type `TextDecorationCollection`, e.g.

```
public static TextDecorationCollection Strikethrough { get; }
```

Apparently they aren't meant to be combined.

So instead of adding any of them to your `TextDeco` property, just set the property like this:

```
TextDeco = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
```

You may however combine two TextDecorations like this:

```
TextDeco = new TextDecorationCollection(
    Enumerable.Concat(TextDecorations.Strikethrough, TextDecorations.Underline));
```

Or more, by recursively calling Concat:

```
TextDeco = new TextDecorationCollection(
    Enumerable.Concat(TextDecorations.Strikethrough,
        Enumerable.Concat(TextDecorations.Underline, TextDecorations.OverLine)));
```

Comment: But you can combine them if you replace the entire collection with a new one: `var td = TextDeco.Clone();
                td.Add(TextDecorations.Strikethrough);
                td.Add(TextDecorations.Underline);
                TextDeco = td;`